# Unable to get w3 total cache page caching to work with my cookies

Tags: wordpress, w3-total-cache, fragment-caching

I have dynamic phone numbers in various parts of my website (header/footer/inner pages) that pull the correct phone number through a stored cookie.

The cookies are stored by a query string that contains a unique ID (ex. wwww.mydomain.com/a/1300) which stores a unique phone number.

My problem is when I enable page caching, the functionality breaks and it does not show the right phone number.

Enabling fragment caching makes it work to a certain extent:

1. the phone numbers show, but only when I refresh the page and not when I navigate through the website
2. The cookie is not always been stored/replaced when loading a different unique ID.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated, it has me stumped.

Comment: if you disable wt3c then its work??

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/61838/exclude-content-from-w3-total-cache

Comment: Yes disabling it works, particularly the page cache. The site is pretty bulky so I was hoping to have it working with page caching enabled.

Comment: I tried excluding the pages/cookies that execute that code, but that didn't help

Comment: Please write into into wordpress forum or w3tc author regarding this.